# Automount CIFS shares: errors at the start of system

Tags: linux, mount, linux-mint, samba

My OS is Linux Mint 18.1.
I have a NAS in my home net. I used to mount it's volumes via fstab file and everything was fine.
After some upgrading of my PC I added one more partition to mount (on the SSD). And when I added due automount line in my fstab, problems began.

I tried various options. The PC hanged at the start and I had to return default fstab file to continue... At last the system refused to start altogether and I had to reinstall my Linux Mint.

My problem with fstab: I cannot fix the error message. So I decided to use  /etc/rc.local and view errors.
I added such commands in rc.local:

```
mount -t ext4 -L Data /mnt/data
mount -t cifs -o credentials=/home/user/my-sys/.user,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775 //192.168.0.100/Volume_1 /mnt/vol1 2> /home/user/mounterr.log
```

The Data partition is being mounted OK.
The CIFS gives error:
mount error(101): Network is unreachable

Manual launch of this mount command gives OK.
What is the cause of the error during rc.local execution? I'd like to understand - instead of just to use one more way (crone or what else...).

Regards,
Yury

Answer (score 1):

The error `mount error(101): Network is unreachable` means that you attempted the mount before the network came up.

To fix this, add the [`_netdev`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169697) option to your `/etc/fstab` CIFS entry.  `_netdev` means to delay the mount until your network is connected.

Your `/etc/fstab` line should look like this:

```
//192.168.0.100/Volume_1 /mnt/vol1 credentials=/home/user/my-sys/.user,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,_netdev 0 0
```

---

To continue using `/etc/rc.local` for your mount, you'll need to set up a new job (to prevent blocking) that loops until the network is up.

From [this answer in Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/672708/18979):

```
(
until ping -nq -c3 W.X.Y.Z; do
   # Waiting for network
   sleep 1
done
mount -t cifs -o credentials=/home/user/my-sys/.user,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775 //192.168.0.100/Volume_1 /mnt/vol1
)&
```

Replace `W.X.Y.Z` with an IP address that responds to ICMP requests, like your router gateway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Am I right to suppose that addinh _netdev option in a rc.local mount command should make the same? I tried it in rc.local and to no avail.

Comment: @drvlas: `_netdev` is an option for `/etc/fstab`. To run a network mount command in `/etc/rc.local`, you'll have to [add extra code to wait for the network](http://askubuntu.com/a/672708/18979).

Comment: That is it! I wanted to wait the network (rather my PC) to be ready - but I couldn't imagine how to solve it. I changed Eric's code to 1 sec step and put a mount command instead of ssh one. Thank you very much! Would you mind to edit your answer to include mount command in a loop? I think about somebody looking here later :)

Comment: @drvlas: Per your request, I have updated my answer with your preferred mounting method.

Comment: As per my comment in the AskUbuntu link already mentioned, I also had to ensure the file was executable (`sudo chmod 775 /etc/rc.local`) and place `#!/bin/sh -e` at the top: https://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-rc-local-run-on-startup/401090#401090